# Not able to get the center of an object using openCV

Tags: python, opencv

I am not able to properly find the center of a triangle using openCV, the center point was drawn at the bottom tip of the triangle. Can anyone help me what is wrong in the code?

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

import stackImages as stack

img = cv2.imread('triangle.jpg',0)
NewImg = img.copy()
ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(img,127,255,0)
contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, 1, 2)

cnt = contours[0]
M = cv2.moments(cnt)
cx = int(M['m10']/M['m00'])
cy = int(M['m01']/M['m00'])

cv2.circle(NewImg, (cx, cy), 2, (0, 0, 255), 3)

cv2.putText(NewImg, "centroid", (cx, cy),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0, 0, 255), 2)       

while (True):
    #imgStack = stack.stackImages(0.8,([img, NewImg]))
    cv2.imshow('Sample', NewImg)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):    
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        break
```

Original Image:
 [image]

Processed Image:
 [image]

Comment: Can you share also source image without processing to be able to check?

Comment: Original Image added

Comment: first you should use `print()` to see values in variables and `imshow()` to display image after `threshold`, with all `contours`, etc. maybe this way you will see what program i sduing and if it calculates centroid for expected figure. Maybe it found many small figures and you use only one of then instead join all small figures to one big figure. Shortly you have to learn how to debug your code.

Comment: Just get started into openCV and as expected, as I have one object in the picture I thought that it should be treated as one. You are right there are multiple small figure in that triangle, reveled by using a loop in the contours variable. Thanks for the tip

Comment: I get better result with `ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(new_img, 210, 255, 0)` - it gives me filled triangle instead of only border of triangle. And this gives me center in better place but I'm not sure if it is ideal place.

Answer (score 2):

You may find multiple contours, and you want the one with the biggest area.

```
# Sort all contours by increasing area
contours_s = sorted(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)

# Find the second largest contour (the largest is the entire image
cnt = contours_s[-2]

copy = cv2.cvtColor(thresh, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)
cv2.drawContours(copy, [cnt], 0, (0, 0, 255))
cv2.imshow(copy)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In Opencv the object needs to be in white and the background black, so when you are applying threshold use `cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV` as the third argument.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with your code. Just cos of you didn't choose the mode for [findContours()](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga17ed9f5d79ae97bd4c7cf18403e1689a) and its choosing the default one and finding outer or some other contours. Just change your line with this:

```
contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have triangle as the largest contour to be returned, you can apply edge detection. Also its better to use `grab_contours` from `imutils` to avoid errors in getting the contours.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import imutils

img = cv2.imread('triangle.jpg',0)
NewImg = img.copy()
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(img, (3, 3), 0)
edged = cv2.Canny(blur, 50, 200)

cnts = cv2.findContours(edged, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)
cnt = sorted(cnts, key = cv2.contourArea, reverse = True)[0]    

M = cv2.moments(cnt)
cx = int(M['m10']/M['m00'])
cy = int(M['m01']/M['m00'])

cv2.circle(NewImg, (cx, cy), 2, (0, 0, 255), 3)

cv2.putText(NewImg, "centroid", (cx, cy),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0, 0, 255), 2)       

while (True):
    cv2.imshow('Sample', NewImg)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):    
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        break
```